# Android : jquery mobile textbox overlap on fixed header while scrolling

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Android : jquery mobile textbox overlap on fixed header while scrolling

While user click on any text box and start scrolling, the focused text box overlap(showing above) the fixed header.

Please find the image from following link :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk6nzeeqrx68uai/Screenshot_2013-10-01-10-19-39-2.png

any suggestions greatly helpful.

Comment: you have this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">?

Comment: no, i haven't place this.

Comment: add css in inputbox position:fixed

Comment: same result. Actually while clicking on the textbox and scrolling up  this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by making the position of the header to absolute instead of fixed.

And add this line to AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: it will be under activity like this <activity
            android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_hello_world" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>